# Subscribe to feed in Thunderbird from the command line?

Tags: linux, firefox, command-line, thunderbird, rss

From reading around the web, it looks like Firefox's "quick view" of an RSS feed sometimes lets you "Subscribe to this feed using" Thunderbird.  For whatever reason, that's not an automatically-added option with my setup (FF 3.5.something + Thunderbird 3.0.something on Linux), so I figured I could just "Choose Application...", point at the Thunderbird binary, and be on my way.  Not so -- nothing appears to happen.  If I run thunderbird from the command line as

```
thunderbird "http://path/to/feed"
```

the app launches as normal.  If it's already running, absolutely nothing happens.

Is this impossible?  Is there some mojo I can pass Firefox to tell it that Thunderbird exists?  Should I just suck it up and copy/paste the URLs manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, of course I'll find the answer *minutes* after I post this question.  For others with the same problem, see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=329235).  In short, you need to call thunderbird with "-mail feed:(your link)".  Because, of course, you add an RSS feed in *mail* mode....  WTF?